# How to encrypt a folder which contains different kinds of files in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

I am working on a note taking application and I need to encrypt package/folder (Each folder is noting but independent book) and folder contains different kind of files or sub-folders(.png,audio,plist). 
What is the recommended way of encrypting a folder(entire package)?

My ideas

1. Recursively go through contents of folder and encrypting each file
   independently.
2. Encrypting the root folder (I am not sure how to do
       it)

I created a sample notebook in apple Pages application and encrypted http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/12/password-protect-iwork-document/ , when I see the encrypted contents the apple is doing each file based encryption i guess.

I thought of using encryption methods which is using by apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303